# Reading and printing from a text file in separate lines?

Tags: python

So below I have my code which has to read from a file to print the file's contents. My question is how would I print the lines in the file separately so they don't all print at once but only if they are needed?

```
input = input('Type:')

if input == ('input'):
        text_file = open("read.txt", "r")
        print (text_file.read(39))

        text_file.close()

elif input == ('input'):
        text_file = open("read.txt", "r")
        print (text_file.read(39))

        text_file.close()

elif input == ('input'):
        text_file = open("read.txt", "r")
        print (text_file.read(39))

        text_file.close()

elif input == ('input'):
        text_file = open("read.txt", "r")
        print (text_file.read(39))

        text_file.close()

elif input == ('input'):
        text_file = open("read.txt", "r")
        print (text_file.read(39))

        text_file.close()

elif input == ('input'):
        text_file = open("read.txt", "r")
        print (text_file.read(39))

        text_file.close()
```

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: Your current response to all your `if/elif` cases is to `print (text_file.read(39))`. They're all identical. What is the structure of the file you're reading?

Comment: Ok. But in order to get reasonable help, you should show a snippet of the text file, so that people know what you're actually reading in.

Comment: What's your reason for erasing your question? It's bad form to nuke your question after it's been answered. It reeks of, "I don't want to get caught asking about homework on the Internet."

Comment: Please don't do that. If you really need to delete it, flag it for moderator attention and request that they delete it for you.

Comment: @Lopin No. Don't do that either. If it really is such a big deal, you could mod flag and ask that the question be disassociated with your account. Make sure you are detailed and give your reasons for wanting it disassociated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a dictionary as shown in the example below. The advantage is that you can use a range of line numbers and it will also simplify the code:

```
import fileinput

plines = {'wifi':1,'storage':4}
user_input = input('Welcome to the troubleshooting system, please state which category you have having issues with:')

for line in fileinput.input("task2_solutions.txt"):
    if fileinput.lineno() == plines[user_input]:
        print line
```

Comment: Thank you for this! It works exactly how I envisioned it.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the line number of the needed response and text file is not that big, you could read lines of the file into a list.

```
text_file = open("task2_solutions.txt", "r")
responses = text_file.read().split("\n")
text_file.close()
```

Then you could access the appropriate response by indexing the known line number in the list:

```
if user_input == ('wifi'):
    print(response[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could at first read all lines in this file and then use regular expression to seperate these lines according to key words in dictionary. After that you can use dictionary to get what you need.